# urllib2 POST progress monitoring

Tags: python, http, urllib2, http-post

I'm uploading a fairly large file with urllib2 to a server-side script via POST. I want to display a progress indicator that shows the current upload progress. Is there a hook or a callback provided by urllib2 that allows me to monitor upload progress? I know that you can do it with download using successive calls to the connection's read() method, but I don't see a write() method, you just add data to the request.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is possible but you need to do a few things:

- Fake out the urllib2 subsystem into passing a file handle down to httplib by attaching a `__len__` attribute which makes `len(data)` return the correct size, used to populate the Content-Length header.
- Override the `read()` method on your file handle: as httplib calls `read()` your callback will be invoked, letting you calculate the percentage and update your progress bar.

This could work with any file-like object, but I've wrapped `file` to show how it could work with a really large file streamed from disk:

```
import os, urllib2
from cStringIO import StringIO

class Progress(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._seen = 0.0

    def update(self, total, size, name):
        self._seen += size
        pct = (self._seen / total) * 100.0
        print '%s progress: %.2f' % (name, pct)

class file_with_callback(file):
    def __init__(self, path, mode, callback, *args):
        file.__init__(self, path, mode)
        self.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        self._total = self.tell()
        self.seek(0)
        self._callback = callback
        self._args = args

    def __len__(self):
        return self._total

    def read(self, size):
        data = file.read(self, size)
        self._callback(self._total, len(data), *self._args)
        return data

path = 'large_file.txt'
progress = Progress()
stream = file_with_callback(path, 'rb', progress.update, path)
req = urllib2.Request(url, stream)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Output:

```
large_file.txt progress: 0.68
large_file.txt progress: 1.36
large_file.txt progress: 2.04
large_file.txt progress: 2.72
large_file.txt progress: 3.40
...
large_file.txt progress: 99.20
large_file.txt progress: 99.87
large_file.txt progress: 100.00
```

Comment: Why did you put the _len_ method? I don't see where httplib or you use it, what's the purpose?

Comment: It is used in `urllib2` `AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_()` and in `httplib HttpConnect._send_request()`, where `len(<file obj>)` is called to set the `Content-length` header.

Comment: How could you use this function using StringIO?

Answer (score 1):

[requests 2.0.0 has streaming uploads](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads). This means you can use a generator to yield tiny chunks and print the progress between chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, but [pycurl does have upload/download progress callbacks](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/callbacks.html) you can use.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it to the standard library. This is going to be distributed to Windows users and I don't want them to have to install extra stuff.

Comment: Well if you come up with something, share it here :)

Answer (score 0):

[poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/poster.encode.html) supports this

```
import json
import os
import sys
import urllib2

from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers

def _upload_progress(param, current, total):
    sys.stdout.write(
        "\r{} - {:.0f}%                "
        .format(param.name,
                (float(current) / float(total)) * 100.0))
    sys.stdout.flush()

def upload(request_resource, large_file_path):
    register_openers()
    with open(large_file_path, 'r') as large_file:
        request_data, request_headers = multipart_encode(
            [('file', largs_file)],
            cb=_upload_progress)

        request_headers.update({
            'X-HockeyAppToken': 'we use this for hockeyapp upload'
        })

        upload_request = urllib2.Request(request_resource,
                                         request_data, 
                                         request_headers)
        upload_connection = urllib2.urlopen(upload_request)
        upload_response = json.load(upload_connection)
    print "Done"
```