# Python HTTPConnection file send with httplib, retrieving progress

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, httpresponse, progress

In a django app I'm using a third-party Python [script](http://wiki.blip.tv/index.php/REST_Upload_Python_Script) to allow users to upload files to blip.tv through httplib.HTTPConnection.send on an EC2 instance. Since these files are generally large I will use a message queue to process the upload asynchronously (RabbitMQ/Celery), and give feedback on the progress to the user in the frontend.

The httpconnection and send are done in this part of the script:

```
host, selector = urlparts = urlparse.urlsplit(url)[1:3]
h = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
h.putrequest("POST", selector)
h.putheader("content-type", content_type)
h.putheader("content-length", len(data))
h.endheaders()
h.send(data)    
response = h.getresponse()
return response.status, response.reason, response.read()
```

The getresponse() is returned after the file transfer is completed, how do I write out the progress (assuming something with stdout.write) so I can write this value to the cache framework for display (djangosnippets 678/679)?  Alternatively if there is a better practice for this, I'm all ears!

**EDIT:**

Since I've gone with urllib2 and used a tip from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925028/urllib2-post-progress-monitoring) to override the read() of the file to get the upload progress.  Furthermore I'm using poster to generate the multipart urlencode.  Here's the latest code:

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
def Upload(video_id, username, password, title, description, filename):

    class Progress(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self._seen = 0.0

        def update(self, total, size, name):
            self._seen += size
            pct = (self._seen / total) * 100.0
            print '%s progress: %.2f' % (name, pct)

    class file_with_callback(file):
        def __init__(self, path, mode, callback, *args):
            file.__init__(self, path, mode)
            self.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            self._total = self.tell()
            self.seek(0)
            self._callback = callback
            self._args = args

        def __len__(self):
            return self._total

        def read(self, size):
            data = file.read(self, size)
            self._callback(self._total, len(data), *self._args)
            return data

    progress = Progress()
    stream = file_with_callback(filename, 'rb', progress.update, filename)

    datagen, headers = multipart_encode({
                                        "post": "1",
                                        "skin": "xmlhttprequest",
                                        "userlogin": "%s" % username,
                                        "password": "%s" % password,
                                        "item_type": "file",
                                        "title": "%s" % title.encode("utf-8"),
                                        "description": "%s" % description.encode("utf-8"),                                             
                                         "file": stream
                                         })    

    opener = register_openers()

    req = urllib2.Request(UPLOAD_URL, datagen, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()
```

This works though only for file path inputs, rather than an InMemoryUploadedFile that comes from a form input (request.FILES), since it is trying to read the file already saved in memory I suppose, and I get a TypeError on line:  "stream = file_with_callback(filename, 'rb', progress.update, filename)":

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found
```

How can I achieve the same progress reporting with the user-uploaded file?  Also, will this consume alot of memory reading out the progress like this, perhaps an upload solution to this [download progress for urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028517/python-urllib2-progress-hook) will work better, but how to implement...   Help is sooo welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the [poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/poster.encode.html) library has a callback hook in multipart_encode, which can be used to get the progress out (upload or download).  Good stuff...

Although i suppose I technically answered this question, I'm sure there are other ways to skin this cat, so i'll post more if I find other methods or details for this.

Here's the code:

```
def prog_callback(param, current, total):
    pct = 100 - ((total - current ) *100 )/ (total) 
    print "Progress: %s " % pct    


datagen, headers = multipart_encode({
                                    "post": "1",
                                    "skin": "xmlhttprequest",
                                    "userlogin": "%s" % username,
                                    "password": "%s" % password,
                                    "item_type": "file",
                                    "title": "%s" % title.encode("utf-8"),
                                    "description": "%s" % description.encode("utf-8"),                                             
                                     "file": filename
                                     }, cb=prog_callback)    

opener = register_openers()

req = urllib2.Request(UPLOAD_URL, datagen, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
return response.read()
```