# How to get upload/download progress using python requests.Session()

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I was studying https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python

The sample uses `requests.Session().get()` and `requests.Session().put()` to implement the download/upload requests.

I found some link [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery/8758614#8758614) but it didn't seem fit the above python sample.

Is there any way like registering an event handler in `requests.Session()`, and getting the progress in that handler?

Comment: Most Python libraries are implemented synchronously. You may not be able to do what you want.

Comment: It seems that the better way is to generate the url in the server side (python), pass to webpage, and actually request content in the client side?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909900/progress-of-python-requests-post ?

Comment: @JulienPalard the link is a nice solution. It is done in the server side. But like the author said, it's a workaround, so I am somehow conservative to it. I am thinking the solution of my above comment, or there is an even simpler solution.