# How to use a Seafile generated upload-link w/o authentication token from command line

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, http-upload, seafile-server

With Seafile one is able to create a public upload link (e.g. `https://cloud.seafile.com/u/d/98233edf89/`) to upload files via Browser w/o authentication.

Seafile webapi does not support any upload w/o authentication token.

How can I use such kind of link from command line with curl or from python script?

Answer (score 9):

needed 2 hours to find a solution with curl, it needs two steps:

1. make a get-request to the public uplink url with the `repo-id` as query parameter as follows:

`curl 'https://cloud.seafile.com/ajax/u/d/98233edf89/upload/?r=f3e30b25-aad7-4e92-b6fd-4665760dd6f5' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'`

The answer is (json) a id-link to use in next upload-post e.g.:

`{"url": "https://cloud.seafile.com/seafhttp/upload-aj/c2b6d367-22e4-4819-a5fb-6a8f9d783680"}`

2. Use this link to initiate the upload post:

`curl 'https://cloud.seafile.com/seafhttp/upload-aj/c2b6d367-22e4-4819-a5fb-6a8f9d783680' -F file=@./tmp/index.html -F filename=index.html -F parent_dir="/my-repo-dir/"`

The answer is json again, e.g.

`[{"name": "index.html", "id": "0a0742facf24226a2901d258a1c95e369210bcf3", "size": 10521}]`

done ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# this script depend on jq,check it first
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
if ! command -v jq &> /dev/null
then
    echo -e "${RED}jq could not be found${NC}, installed and restart plz!\n"
    exit
fi


usage () { echo "Usage : $0 -u <username> -p <password> -h <seafile server host> -f <upload file path> -d <parent dir default value is /> -r <repo id> -t <print debug info switch off/on,default off>"; }

# parse args
while getopts "u:p:h:f:d:r:t:" opts; do
   case ${opts} in
      u) USER=${OPTARG} ;;
      p) PASSWORD=${OPTARG} ;;
      h) HOST=${OPTARG} ;;
      f) FILE=${OPTARG} ;;
      d) PARENT_DIR=${OPTARG} ;;
      r) REPO=${OPTARG} ;;
      t) DEBUG=${OPTARG} ;;
      *) usage; exit;;
   esac
done

# those args must be not null
if [ ! "$USER" ] || [ ! "$PASSWORD" ] || [ ! "$HOST" ] || [ ! "$FILE" ] || [ ! "$REPO" ]
then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

# optional args,set default value

[ -z "$DEBUG" ] && DEBUG=off

[ -z "$PARENT_DIR" ] && PARENT_DIR=/

# print vars key and value when DEBUG eq on
[[ "on" == "$DEBUG" ]] && echo -e "USER:${USER} PASSWORD:${PASSWORD} HOST:${HOST} FILE:${FILE} PARENT_DIR:${PARENT_DIR} REPO:${REPO} DEBUG:${DEBUG}"

# login and get token
TOKEN=$(curl -s --location --request POST "${HOST}/api2/auth-token/" --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode "username=${USER}" --data-urlencode "password=${PASSWORD}" | jq -r ".token")

[ -z "$TOKEN" ] && echo -e "${RED}login seafile faild${NC}, call your administrator plz!\n" && exit 1

# gen upload link 
UPLOAD_LINK=$(curl -s --header "Authorization: Token ${TOKEN}" "${HOST}/api2/repos/${REPO}/upload-link/?p=${PARENT_DIR}" | jq -r ".")

[ -z "$UPLOAD_LINK" ] && echo -e "${RED}get upload link faild${NC}, call your administrator plz!\n" && exit 1

# upload file
UPLOAD_RESULT=$(curl -s --header "Authorization: Token ${TOKEN}" -F file="@${FILE}" -F filename=$(basename ${FILE}) -F parent_dir="${PARENT_DIR}" -F replace=1 "${UPLOAD_LINK}?ret-json=1")

[ -z "$UPLOAD_RESULT" ] && echo -e "${RED}faild to upload ${FILE}${NC}, call your administrator plz!\n" && exit 1

# print upload result
[[ "on" == "$DEBUG" ]] && echo -e "TOKEN:${TOKEN} UPLOAD_LINK:${UPLOAD_LINK} UPLOAD_RESULT:${UPLOAD_RESULT}"
```

save as `seafile-upload.sh`

```
# ubuntu 
apt install -y jq
# centos 
# yum install -y jq
chmod +x ./seafile-upload.sh

./seafile-upload.sh -u <username> -p <password> -h <seafile server host> -f <upload file path> -d <parent dir default value is /,must be start with /> -r <repo id> -t <print debug info switch off/on,default off>
```

my blog [060-轻量级基于curl的seafile上传脚本](https://juejin.cn/post/6948276424633483300)

official document [web-api/v2.1/file-upload.md](https://download.seafile.com/published/web-api/v2.1/file-upload.md)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Python script for command-line use, based on my observations of the file upload behavior in a browser. Only the upload page link (generated by Seafile) and local file paths are needed.

I have also uploaded the script as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/atomiechen/6afe4042c386e2280fa306951b5a4c3a), and will be updated in time.

### Usage

Setup:

- Install pip package `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` .
- (Optional) Install `requests_toolbelt` and `tqdm` to see real-time upload progess.

```
usage: upload_seafile.py [-h] -l LINK -f FILE [FILE ...] [-v] [--replace]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -l LINK, --link LINK  upload page link (generated by seafile)
  -f FILE [FILE ...], --file FILE [FILE ...]
                        file(s) to upload
  -v, --verbose         show detailed output
  --replace             Replace existing files
```

### Script

Key Logic:

1. Open the upload page and extract `parent_dir` and `token` (login not required).
2. Request the file upload url. The part includes two methods: one refers to the [seafile API](https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-js/blob/master/src/seafile-api.js#L1164) used in the browser, and another incorporates the approach from [lmen6e's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38743242/11854304).
3. Upload the file, where the `parent_dir` parameter is needed.

Code:

```py
# ref: https://gist.github.com/atomiechen/6afe4042c386e2280fa306951b5a4c3a
import re
import argparse
import sys
import copy
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

optional_packages = True
try:
    # optional, for upload progess updates
    from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder, MultipartEncoderMonitor
    from tqdm import tqdm
except ImportError:
    optional_packages = False


def extract_var(script_text, variable_name, default=None):
    if variable_name in script_text:
        # match: var_name: "value" or var_name: 'value' or var_name = "value" or var_name = 'value'
        pattern = re.compile(r'{}\s*[:=]\s*(["\'])(.*?)\1'.format(re.escape(variable_name)))
        match = pattern.search(script_text)
        if match:
            return match.group(2)
    return default

def extract_info_from_html(html_content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    token = parent_dir = repo_id = dir_name = None
    for script in scripts:
        token = extract_var(script.text, 'token', token)
        parent_dir = extract_var(script.text, 'path', parent_dir)
        repo_id = extract_var(script.text, 'repoID', repo_id)
        dir_name = extract_var(script.text, 'dirName', dir_name)
    return token, parent_dir, repo_id, dir_name

def get_html_content(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text

def get_upload_url(api_url):
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json().get('upload_link')
    return None

def get_upload_url2(api_url):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json().get('url')
    return None

def upload_file(upload_url, file_path, fields):
    fields = copy.deepcopy(fields)
    path = Path(file_path)
    filename = path.name
    total_size = path.stat().st_size
    
    if not optional_packages:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            fields["file"] = (filename, f)
            response = requests.post(upload_url, files=fields, params={'ret-json': 'true'})
        return response

    # ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67726532/11854304
    with tqdm(
        desc=filename,
        total=total_size,
        unit="B",
        unit_scale=True,
        unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
            fields["file"] = (filename, f)
            encoder = MultipartEncoder(fields=fields)
            monitor = MultipartEncoderMonitor(
                encoder, lambda monitor: bar.update(monitor.bytes_read - bar.n)
            )
            headers = {"Content-Type": monitor.content_type}
            response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=monitor, params={'ret-json': 'true'})
    return response

def upload_seafile(upload_page_link, file_path_list, replace_file, verbose):
    parsed_results = urlparse(upload_page_link)
    base_url = f"{parsed_results.scheme}://{parsed_results.netloc}"
    if verbose:
        print(f"Input:")
        print(f" * Upload page url: {upload_page_link}")
        print(f" * Files to be uploaded: {file_path_list}")
        print(f" * Replace existing files: {replace_file}")
        print(f"Preparation:")
        print(f" * Base url: {base_url}")

    # get html content
    html_content = get_html_content(upload_page_link)

    # extract variables from html content
    token, parent_dir, repo_id, dir_name = extract_info_from_html(html_content)
    if not parent_dir:
        print(f"Cannot extract parent_dir from HTML content.", file=sys.stderr)
        return 1
    if verbose:
        print(f" * dir_name: {dir_name}")
        print(f" * parent_dir: {parent_dir}")

    # get upload url
    upload_url = None
    if token:
        # ref: https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-js/blob/master/src/seafile-api.js#L1164
        api_url = f'{base_url}/api/v2.1/upload-links/{token}/upload/'
        upload_url = get_upload_url(api_url)
    elif repo_id:
        # ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38743242/11854304
        api_url = upload_page_link.replace("/u/d/", "/ajax/u/d/").rstrip('/') + f"/upload/?r={repo_id}"
        upload_url = get_upload_url2(api_url)
    if not upload_url:
        print(f"Cannot get upload_url.", file=sys.stderr)
        return 1
    if verbose:
        print(f" * upload_url: {upload_url}")

    # prepare payload fields
    fields = {'parent_dir': parent_dir}
    # overwrite file if already present in the upload directory.
    # contributor: hmassias
    # ref: https://gist.github.com/hmassias/358895ef0b2ffaa9e708181b16b554cf
    if replace_file:
        fields["replace"] = "1"

    # upload each file
    print(f"Upload:")
    for idx, file_path in enumerate(file_path_list):
        print(f"({idx+1}) {file_path}")
        try:
            response = upload_file(upload_url, file_path, fields)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print(f"({idx+1}) upload completed: {response.json()}")
            else:
                print(f"({idx+1}) {file_path} ERROR: {response.status_code} {response.text}", file=sys.stderr)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"({idx+1}) {file_path} EXCEPTION: {e}", file=sys.stderr)

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--link', required=True, help='upload page link (generated by seafile)')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', required=True, nargs='+', help='file(s) to upload')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', help='show detailed output')
    parser.add_argument('--replace', action='store_true', help='Replace existing files')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sys.exit(upload_seafile(args.link, args.file, args.replace, args.verbose))
```