# Local file upload progress bar in console using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar, sys, pathlib

I need to upload a file and show its stats to the user (as it shows on the console).
Didn't find any library for this, the function can be as simple as showing the uploaded percentage (`uploaded/filesize*100`) and showing the uploaded size (20/50MB) with the upload speed and ETA.
There's a nice library named `alive-progress` on printing out the progress bar.
but I just don't have any idea on how to do this, like the simpler version of what is done on `youtube-dl`.

Comment: How are you uploading the file? FTP, HTTP, etc? Or are you only concerned with showing the progress bar and good on the upload portion?

Comment: I have post my answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73463922/17915481](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73463922/17915481)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `sys` lib.
Using `stdout` & `flush` [(more details here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019456/usage-of-sys-stdout-flush-method).

```py
import sys, time

lenght_bar = 50

sys.stdout.write("Loading : |%s|" % (" " * lenght_bar))
sys.stdout.write("\b" * (lenght_bar+1)) #use backspace

for i in range(lenght_bar):
    sys.stdout.write("▒")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1) #process

sys.stdout.write("| 100%")
sys.stdout.write("\nDone")

time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thank you! but what about the file size? how can I create a progress-bar dependent on the file size? (so I can determine how much uploaded).

Answer (score 1):

The **tqdm** lib can do this.

```py
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    with tqdm(desc=f"[INFO] Uploading", total=file_size, unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024) as t:
        reader_wrapper = CallbackIOWrapper(t.update, f, "read")
        resp = httpx.post(url, files={'apk_file': reader_wrapper})
```

it looks like:

```
[INFO] Uploading: 100%|██████████| 9.60M/9.60M [00:02<00:00, 3.85MB/s]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. Combining `\r` with `print(text, end='')`.

I don't know how you're getting your `uploaded_size` so there is a sample code that should work anyway.

```py
import time

#Progress bar
def updateProgressBar(size_uploaded, size_file, size_bar=50):
    perc_uploaded = round(size_uploaded / size_file * 100)
    progress = round(perc_uploaded / 100 * size_bar)

    status_bar = f"-{'▒' * progress}{' ' * (size_bar - progress)}-"
    status_count = f"[{size_uploaded}/{size_file}MB]"
    #add your status_eta
    #add your status_speed

    print(f"\r{status_bar} | {status_count} | {perc_uploaded}%", end='')
    #using the carriage-return (\r) to "overwrite" the previous line



#For the demo
file_size = 2**16 #fake file size
uploaded_size = 0
while uploaded_size < file_size:
    uploaded_size += 1

    updateProgressBar(uploaded_size, file_size)

print("\nDone!")

time.sleep(10)
```

I suggest that each time you're getting an update about your uploaded_size/ETA/upload_speed you call the `updateProgressBar` method.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should run on `Python 3.7` or later.
Just edit `SRC_FILE` and `DEST_URL` before copy and paste.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import os
import aiofiles
import math
from tqdm import tqdm

async def file_sender(file_name=None, chunk_size=65536):
    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
    chunks = max(1, int(math.ceil(file_size / chunk_size)))
    progress = tqdm(desc=f"Uploading", total=file_size, unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
    async with aiofiles.open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        for _ in range(chunks):
            chunk = await f.read(chunk_size)
            progress.update(len(chunk))
            yield chunk

async def async_http_upload_from_file(src, dst):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await session.post(dst, data=file_sender(file_name=src))

SRC_FILE = 'path/to/your/file'
DEST_URL = 'path/to/your/url'

asyncio.run(async_http_upload_from_file(SRC_FILE, DEST_URL))
```

I think you can try using this URL for testing:

```
DEST_URL = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
```