Web uploader using python "requests" to upload 7G file occupies all CPU resources
We have this snippet to upload a file to a web api
import requests
import json

api_url = "https://ourserver/ourserverfolder/api/auth/Login"
dto = { "username": "ourusename", "password": "ourpassword" }
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' }
response = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(dto), headers=headers)
response_obj = response.json()
bearer = response_obj["token"]

upload_url = "https://anotherserver/anotherserverfolder/UploadFile"
filename = r"D:\bigfile.zip"
filenamewithoutfolder = filename.split('\\')[-1]
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    file = (filenamewithoutfolder, f, 'application/x-zip')
    upload_files = { "file": file }
    upload_headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer }
    upload_response = requests.post(upload_url, files=upload_files, headers=upload_headers, 
verify=False)

When we upload smaller files, it uploads them without a noticeable CPU impact.
However, when I am trying to upload a 7G file, it occupies all cpu on my computer.
Everything just stops. Like we had came back in time and was running Windows 95 or some other operating system with cooperative multitasking.
Why?
I can also notice that the program takes up memory in a linear proportion to the time it has executed.
I have some ideas

The code might still in some way cause the file to be stored as a byte buffer.
The multipart/form-data creation might check the whole file to come up with a suitable delimiter? Instead of just guessing?


related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909900/progress-of-python-requests-post
